# MS Access - Max function with Date not working

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Okay, so I built a database that allows me to keep track of calls being made to potential customers. Basically, the user generates a call list, and after calling each customer, they update the Call Status field in one of my tables to either "Person Reached", "Line Busy", "Disconnected Number", etc.

The problem I am having is that when I run the "Generate Call List" query (which I use to populate the Call List table), I am getting people who have already been reached. I have a condition that excludes anyone with a Call Status of "Person Reached", but for some reason it's not working. Here's the SQL.

```
SELECT [Telephone Status].Patient_ID, Max([Telephone Status].Date_Called) 
AS [Date Last Called]
FROM [Telephone Status]
WHERE ((([Telephone Status].Call_Status_Details)="Call Back Later") AND
(([Telephone Status].Call_Status)<>"Person Reached"))
GROUP BY [Telephone Status].Patient_ID;
```

I thought that by using the Max function with the Date_Called field, that I would be excluding individuals who have a "Person Reached" status from the most recent call (Max), but I am still getting people who have been reached.

How can I check for this condition ("Person Reached") for the most recent Date_Called entry for each participant, and exclude them if the condition is True (Person was reached)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The problem I am having is that when I run the "Generate Call List" query (which I use to populate the Call List table), I am getting people who have already been reached.*

And how do you know that statement to be true?  I think you need to examine the data in the [Telephone Status] table ... the Date_Called, Call_Status_Details, and Call_Status fields for one of the Patient_ID which was erroneously included on the call list.

*I have a condition that excludes anyone with a Call Status of "Person Reached", but for some reason it's not working.*

Not exactly ...

```
SELECT
    ts.Patient_ID,
    Max(ts.Date_Called) AS [Date Last Called]
FROM [Telephone Status] AS ts
WHERE
    ts.Call_Status_Details = "Call Back Later"
    AND ts.Call_Status <> "Person Reached"
GROUP BY ts.Patient_ID;
```

... so you have two criteria which both must be True.

Some ways a "person reached" could be included in the call list query are:

1. Call_Status_Details = "Call Back Later" but Call_Status is anything
   other than "Person Reached", such as "Person R eached"; Person
   Reachd"; etc.
2. A record with Call_Status_Details = "Call Back Later", a more recent
   Date_Called than the last Call_Status = "Person Reached", but
   some other valid value for Call_Status.
3. Indexes for those fields are corrupt.

The first is a data quality issue.  You need to verify the data is consistently stored as you and your query expect.

I don't know about the second possibility.  It depends on your business rules and how they are implemented.

The last possibility, index corruption, appears to be rare in my experience, but I've heard it can happen.  Compact & Repair could fix it.  See Tony Towes' [Corrupt Microsoft Access MDBs FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm) for more detailed information.

**Edit**: You have a "Generate Call List" query which populates a Call List table.  That is a situation where the Call List table could get out of sync with the latest updates to the [Telephone Status] table.  It would be better to use the query itself for the call list rather than duplicating (possibly outdated) information in a separate table.

Comment: Hey Hans, I don't really have a data quality problem as the callers are selecting the Call_Status from a combo box. Also, I think your suggestion for using the query itself for the call list is valid, but I don't think it will work for my situation. The reason is because whenever I generate a call list, I have to split the number of people to be called by the number of staff I have working. So, I populate the call list table first, then I use an update query to assign the calls to certain staff members (continued below..)

Comment: So if I have 1000 people on the call list and 4 people working, each person is assigned 250 people to call. Unfortunately, I don't know really know how to accomplish the same result with just a query. Finally, I know this is probably not the most ideal set up, but while the Call List table may not always be up to date (even though I do update it daily), each staff member uses a custom query to generate their call list. Besides pulling only records that have been assigned to them, it also eliminates any records where the person has been contacted today.

Comment: So, I think I may just have to check for the "Person Reached" is this second query as opposed to the first. It's funny how everything starts to make sense when you type it out. Thanks Hans for always helping! Your answer above is valid and could help people in similar situations, so I'll accept it.